# C converts HEX value from emacs into the incorrect value

Tags: c, emacs, hex

in a file, i have used `m-x ucs-insert` to insert a hex character `9e` (which in emacs shows up as `\236`). however, when this is read in by the C program, `9e` is becoming `0x9ec2`. Where is this `c2` coming from and how do i get rid of it??

Comment: You need to post the code that you are using to read this character.

Comment: if i had the code, i certainly would. it's a binary executable (code i did not write). all i can tell you is that i read the string out of the .txt file using fscanf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unicode character U+009E is represented in UTF-8 as the bytes C2 9E (see this handy [converter](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html)). It's likely that your emacs is set up to save files in UTF-8. Try loading the file in emacs with `M-x find-file-literally` and see if it comes out as `\302\236` (octal representation of C2 9E). If so, you'll be able to delete the `\302` and see if that makes the program run better.